# Glass Mapper RenderLink double quotation marks

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper

I am using Glass Mapper with Sitecore 8. Glass Mapper renders links with single quotation marks, which goes awry when the link text itself has a quote in it:

```xml
<a href='' class=' ' title='Coroner's Request' >
```

How can I get Glass Mapper to use double quotes in links?
I notice that the option has been added in [a recent change](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/101), which has included a [new property in the GlassHtml class](http://docs.glass.lu/html/62872f48-9fad-6f62-eeef-d10bf8399fcf.htm). But I can't seem to find how to configure it anywhere! What have I missed?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a field of `GlassHtml` class. You would need to set it e.g. by executing this code:

```cs
Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml.QuotationMark = "\"";
```

It's a static field so it's enough to do this only once e.g. in `<initialize>` pipeline.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.